# Программа для рассылки писем

Tags: windows, email

Есть папка с картинками. Есть список excel с адресами EMail. Ищу программу, в которую можно загрузить картинки и список. Дальше первая картинка уходит на первый адрес из списка, вторая картинка на второй соответственно. Можно ли решить данную задачу с помощью какого-нибудь софта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хочешь сервис то вот (SendSay) *https://sendsay.ru/*
Если программа то вот (Zennolab) *https://zennolab.com/ru/*

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).